# Gedit malfunctioning

Tags: 18.04, gedit

I am new to Ubuntu and well, recently (after 3 days of using it) my text editor (gedit) started malfunctioning. The whole window isn't visible, the background of the app in background is visible when I start it (almost like gedit window is transparent). I can, however only type stuff but backspace (or delete) doesn't seem to work.

Screenshots :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think,

just delete file `$HOME/.xinputrc` with the following command

```
rm -f ~/.xinputrc
sudo init 6
```

and reboot.

Hope this helps.